# Windows attempts to chkdsk a phantom Volume at every startup

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, partitioning, chkdsk

The question(s) of this post are the following:

1. This Windows 8.1 installation is executing what appears to be a `chkdsk` on every boot, specifying the following message at boot: `Scanning and Repairing \\?\Volume{4293f4d0-c749-11e6-88`
2. This windows installation appears to register a Volume for hardware I cannot identify. This volume is missing a lot of properties when queried by Powershell's GWMI. How do you stop windows from creating this volume and/or deleting this presumed phantom volume?

The value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute` has not been changed (`autocheck autochk *`).

I have deleted the following entries from the registery. The entry at `CPC\Volume\` is reinstated by a reboot with the property `Generation=1` changed from `Generation=3`.

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-266297146-606339484-1538558864-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\`: http://pastebin.com/4et43xa5

`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-266297146-606339484-1538558864-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{4293f4d0-c749-11e6-88bf-9fb7251967bc}`: http://pastebin.com/1BNdvxLd

CPC reinstation: http://pastebin.com/FMpiEAKK

mountvol output (`a5222769-348a-48b3-9117-3dc81a6892b3` is `WINRETOOLS`)

```
\\?\Volume{07c21702-56c0-4a5a-b75c-1faf4a4c06d7}\
    C:\

\\?\Volume{a5222769-348a-48b3-9117-3dc81a6892b3}\
    *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

\\?\Volume{4293f4d0-c749-11e6-88bf-9fb7251967bc}\
    *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

\\?\Volume{7ad4f34f-c7f5-11e6-8043-806e6f6e6963}\
    D:\

The EFI System Partition is mounted at T:\
```

diskpart list vol

```
 Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
 ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
 Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
 Volume 1     C   OS           NTFS   Partition     68 GB  Healthy    Boot
 Volume 2     T   ESP          FAT32  Partition    500 MB  Healthy    System
 Volume 3     U   WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partition    500 MB  Healthy    Hidden
 Volume 4     V                RAW    Partition      9 GB  Healthy    Hidden
```

This is a paste of `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume` with regards to this VolumeName. As you can see this Volume has basically no information:

http://pastebin.com/HcJeR26R

The full output is here: http://pastebin.com/QbYH0H4q

HD Partitions:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             500 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved           128 MB   541 MB
  Partition 3    Recovery           500 MB   669 MB
  Partition 4    Primary             68 GB  1169 MB
  Partition 5    Recovery             9 GB    69 GB
```

System:

Windows 8.1 updated from 8

BCD is minimalist. Nothing special in there: http://pastebin.com/4CjtcyRe

Answer (score 0):

The phantom partition was the 9gb PBR Image dell recovery partition with corruption. Deleting this partition with Computer Management.Storage Management resolved this issue.